# How to get my custom table data from magento 2

Tags: magento2, database

I have created a new table using custom module and stored value to this table, now, i need to get table data in block php file from database in magento 2, How to achieve this?

`TableName="email_format"` `columns="customerid"` and `"format"` now,  i need to retrieve customer id and format value from table.

Thanks,

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1) I Assume you have created Model and Collection file associated with that tables.

2) In a Block PHP file constructor add one argument (Dependency Injection) like below and store it in a class member variable.

```
 public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Namespace\Modulename\Model\ModelNameFactory $modelNameFactory,

    array $data = array()
) {
    $this->_modelFactory = $modelFactory;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
```

3) Prepare a public method in your block to access collection like below.

```
public function getCollection(){

    return $this->_modelFactory->create()->getCollection();

}
```

4) Loop through each of the collection result.

**Hope, this will help you.**

Comment: Can we inject \Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\ModelName\Collection directly in to constructor?

Answer (score 12):

You can directly get custom table using objectmanager concept,

```
    $objectManager =   \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $connection = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection')->getConnection('\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION'); 
    $result1 = $connection->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM email_format");

echo "<pre>";print_r($result1);
```

Or

This is proper way using block:

```
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Namespace\Module\Model\ModuleFactory $modelFactory,

    array $data = array()
) {
    $this->_modelFactory = $modelFactory;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
```

You can get collection by factory methods:

```
public function getCollection(){

    return $this->_modelFactory->create()->getCollection();

}
```

Comment: This is not correct way

Comment: Using the object manager directly is definitely not the most elegant way of doing it. Try to stick to dependency injection