# Magento 2: How to fetch data from custom table and show in Cart page

Tags: magento2, database, cart, shipping, shopping-cart

Magento 2: How to fetch data from a custom table and show in Cart page
I want to show custom table data values in cart page and add those values in total.
Please help me with some tutorials or code.
Thanks

Comment: Does this help? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92774/how-to-add-fee-to-order-totals-in-magento-2

Comment: @simonthesorcerer the module worked static so its add only 100 value in total I want to fetch the value from the table (dynamic) and show in cart.

Comment: @SukumarGorai its duplicate but i want to fetch data from table and show in that fee field.

Comment: @jhonjhondoe Please create model for custom table OR if model is already created then just get data by that model and show

Comment: @MukeshPrajapati i created module and custom table as well so i want to fetch data from that table and show in cart page? so i need any code can u help me in chat ?

Comment: @jhonjhondoe yes you can get data by model so first check there in module is there model folder ?

Comment: yes model folder there

Comment: @jhonjhondoe ok then you can get data by that model anywhere.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112291/how-to-get-my-custom-table-data-from-magento-2

Comment: @MukeshPrajapati, please share the code to show the value in cart summary, which file we need to edit \?