# I need to add 2 fields on My Account Page

Tags: magento2, custom, myaccount

How to add two custom fields of customer in magento from database after registration.

Comment: Please describe your question. @AkashKilledar

Comment: I need to add Age and Birth date field in my account page. Values are present in the database. I need to fetch them and show it on my account page of specific user.

Comment: I think you have to make custom extension for it.  Or this will help you. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112291/how-to-get-my-custom-table-data-from-magento-2

Comment: Could you please let me know in which table values are present ?